# Is Confluent Control Center extensible?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-control-center

Confluent Control Center seems to be modular, but I haven't found any documentation on how one might build their own plugin for custom management of Kafka.  Is Control Center extensible and is there any public documentation, articles, etc. that serve as a guide to building a new component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confluent Control Center is part of their [enterprise license](https://docs.confluent.io/current/control-center/installation/licenses.html), so accessing the source code it's out of the question. Also, it's not a mature enough product yet to have its own developer kit, so you can't create 3rd party components either.

You can try giving them some feedback, and maybe they will incorporate this feature at some point!

Answer (score 1):

It is closed source, so there would be no such documentation on extending it.

Most "plugins" are supported via external REST actions (KSQL, Connect, Schema Registry browser, etc).

Thus, you could inject frontend code with something like TamperMonkey, but that is not Control Center specific.